# Fundamentals of Output Characteristics of a BJT, what is the difference between load line and output characteristics?

Tags: bjt, npn

[image: Typical Output Characteristics]

In any transistor, we plot the output characteristics, i.e. effect of change in Vce on Ic.
Next, we write the KVL equation on the transistor, i.e. Vcc = IcRc + Vce and plot the load line from this equation. 
So, now we have 2 relations between Vce and Ic - output characteristics and load line. 
Why do we 2 plots for the same 2 variables, when will each be used and what all do they signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transistor characteristics say what the *transistor* does.  The load line says what the *resistor* does.  The intersection of the transistor characteristic lines with the resistor load line says what the *amplifier* does.

Comment: Very original and impressive explanation of this arrangement... but unappreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The load line plot does a poor job of demonstrating the non-linear voltage error of a large swing output.
But it does tell you the base current needed vs output voltage.

A better plot would be error voltage vs output for a given load current V/R and current or voltage  gain.

But for high current and full swing, you can see the spacing between base steps changes quickly below Vce=2V. This tells you the difference in peaks gets worse and this means harmonic distortion. So avoid Vce<2V.

**hFE begins to drop here to the left of the M point defined by the saturation zone, but depends greatly on collector current.**

**The low current also has poor hFE so <10% max current Ic should also be avoided.**

This is defined by the N point and must also be avoided so Q is the middle of the M-N range.

This means for the poor simple H-bias design the useful output swing is reduced in this case to 2/3 Vcc.  This can be easily fixed by adding a Rcb negative feedback and series input R with other changes needed , but then output linearity can be improved by the amount of gain reduction.

Comment: The load line stuff really seems a remnant from vacuum tube days, to me.  I've never used it for designing BJT amplifiers.

Comment: @TimWescott. It is: my 1983 high school electronic textbook deals extensively with load lines in the context of vaacum tubes, BJTs, JFETs and MOSFETs. However, it is used as a design tool only for vaacum tubes.

Comment: @TimWescott What's the more modern procedure? I don't remember learning anything other than the load line. But I also don't remember very much.

Comment: I've always designed a heavily fed-back amplifier and used the calculated gain (backed up by measured, of course), and taken the output swing as being from VCC down to saturation for single-ended.  Push-pull amplifiers are usually complicated enough that a load line per se doesn't mean much.

Comment: Unless you choose negative feedback (preferred) you accept the fact there is significant distortion on BJT’s when Imax/Imin >10 and Vce <2. THIS can be quantified, SUPPORTED AND PROVEN

Answer (score 0):

The important piece of missing information is that in the circuit, current through the resistor flows into the collector -- both currents are Ic, and they are the same.

So, for a given base current, the blue line shows you how Ic changes with Vce, as determined by the transistor.

The red line shows you how Ic changes with Vce, as determined by the resistor.

Since these currents are the *same*, the actual Vce and Ic in the circuit will be the point where the blue and red lines meet.

Comment: Yes, that was my question, why are there 2 different graphs for the same current?